# Rails -- cookies adds an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, cookies, server

I store an array to cookies in someone method:

```
def someone
  cookies[:test] = JSON.generate [@page.image, @page.title]
end
```

But I want to cookies[:test] can store more information as "<<" not "=",
like(will get an error):

```
def someone
  cookies[:test] << JSON.generate [@page.image, @page.title]
end
```

Now, `cookies[:test].inspect` is `[[@page.image, @page.title], [@page.image, @page.title]]`.
How to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to append directly to the cookie; it's stored as a string (which JSON.generate returns), so you need to deserialize, append, then reserialize and store:

```
current = JSON.parse cookies[:test]
current << [@page.image, @page.title]
cookies[:test] = JSON.generate current
```

Or a little more succinctly:

```
cookies[:test] = (JSON.parse(cookies[:test]) + [[@page.image, @page.title]]).to_json
```